# Delete Heroku migrations

Tags: django, heroku

I read advices how to delete migrations but I don't understand what I'm doing and it's not working for me.

History. One day I had an issue when I added or renamed a model fields locally. So I was tired with that issue and I deleted all migrations and migrate again. And all was OK. But I remember that I will have a big problem when I will deploy on Heroku.

So the days are gone. And now it happened. :(((
I make migrations, migrate to a server database. Pushed my code, but.. it wrote me:

> relation "accounts_goal" does not exist
> LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "accounts_goal"

I understand it happened because locally I have 0001 and 0002 migrations, but on the server there are 0012 and etc. migrations. I think I need to delete all old migrations on the server. But I don't know how to do that. Help me please! Thank you)

Comment: "I read advices how to delete migrations but I don't understand what I'm doing"—deleting migrations is usually a bad idea, _especially_ if you don't understand what you are doing. "I understand it happened because locally I have 0001 and 0002 migrations, but on the server there are 0012 and etc. migrations"—why would the migrations differ between machines? Are you talking about migration _files_, or records in the migration database table?

Comment: I didn't know that was a bad idea, but I read the advice from the internet)) And now I think it was a bad idea . I think I'm talking about files, cause I deleted all local migration files .py, but didn't with server migration files. And i didn't check the files on Heroku. It's opinion.

Comment: Now I understand the issue appeared cause it can't to find the instance of model. So, I commented the code where it creates and it worked! But in admin panel I want to create the instance and it showed me the same problem... 

Comment: Any help please... I couldn't go into my admin panel. Got the issue:
ProgrammingError at /admin/accounts/goal/
relation "accounts_goal" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "accounts_goal"

Answer (score 0):

At first, do not delete a table from the database before the migration. If you change your model, then manage.py migrate will do the thing. Django cannot detect the direct change of database; only knows the change of model script (makemigrations).

```
Sometimes migration doesn't work for no reasons. In that case, do the following things:
```

1. Undo the change of models.py (comment, delete).
2. manage.py makemigrations app-name.
3. manage.py migrate
4. Change the models.py again (as you wish).
5. Do the migration again.

   Also you can try python manage.py migrate --fake.

   If there is already a table present, Django will see that the initial migration has already been applied since the table is already present with old schema and therefore not taking the new table with different schema into consideration.
   In that case, you need to drop tables in the database you can use python manage.py migrate app-name zero.